# provisioning package does not work to enroll device in Intune

Tags: microsoft, intune

I followed the steps like the Microsoft Docs said but my provisioning package does not enrol my device
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/windows-bulk-enroll

No error message.
I run the package from a usb stick.
We do install the device with our own windows 11 image